# Flutter: Persistent BottomAppBar and BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter, and I am building an app that has `BottomAppBar` which takes the property `bottomNavigationBar:` of `Scaffold()` for my home_screen, because I needed it to be at the bottom of the screen and persistent throughout the pages, and I also need a `BottomNavigationBar` to be persistent also at the top of `BottomAppBar`, but I can't make that happen because `BottomAppBar` already takes the `bottomNavigationBar:` property.

How can I make my `BottomNavigationBar` persistent alongside my `BottomAppBar`?

**Note:** I am using `PageView()` to scroll through my pages and it will be controlled by the `BottomNavigationBar`

**Edit:** attached here is the UI that I am trying to achieve
[image: persistent BottomNavigationBar at the top of BottomAppBar]

**code snippet:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//screens
import 'package:timewise_flutter/screens/calendar_screen.dart';
import 'package:timewise_flutter/screens/covey_quadrants_screen.dart';
import 'package:timewise_flutter/screens/kanban_screen.dart';
import 'package:timewise_flutter/screens/todo_list_screen.dart';

class OverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'overview_screen';

  //const OverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OverviewScreenState createState() => _OverviewScreenState();
}

class _OverviewScreenState extends State<OverviewScreen> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 2);
  int _bottomNavBarCurrentIndex = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
        child: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 16.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Menu',
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('menu icon pressed!');
                  //TODO: show bottom modal bottom sheet
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Pomodoro Timer',
                icon: Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty_rounded),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('pomo icon pressed!');
                  //TODO: show pomodoro timer modal bottom sheet
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                tooltip: 'Add',
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('add icon pressed!');
                  //TODO: show add task modal bottom sheet
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );,
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: (page) {
          setState(() {
            _bottomNavBarCurrentIndex = page;
          });
        },
        children: [
          CalendarScreen(),
          ToDoListScreen(),
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Overview Screen'),
                  BottomNavigationBar(
                    currentIndex: _bottomNavBarCurrentIndex,
                    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    iconSize: 16.0,
                    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                    showSelectedLabels: false,
                    showUnselectedLabels: false,
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded),
                        label: 'Calendar',
                        tooltip: 'Calendar',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.checklist_rounded),
                        label: 'To-Do',
                        tooltip: 'To-Do List',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.panorama_fish_eye_rounded),
                        label: 'Overview',
                        tooltip: 'Overview',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.border_all_rounded),
                        label: 'Covey\'s 4 Quadrants',
                        tooltip: 'Covey\'s 4 Quadrants',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.view_column_rounded),
                        label: 'Kanban Board',
                        tooltip: 'Kanban Board',
                      ),
                    ],
                    onTap: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _bottomNavBarCurrentIndex = index;
                        _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CoveyQuadrantsScreen(),
          KanbanScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you need `BottomAppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar` either one is fine.  If you have specific reason, please include UI images or Code snippet that you tried to achieve for better understanding.

Comment: I will be using the BottomAppBar for some functions, but not to navigate, and the BottomNavigationBar is mainly for navigating through different screens of my app

Comment: I edited my question and added UI and code snippet, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not a standard way in which the mobile app UI should be designed. This will result in bad user experience.

> What if user accidently touches on `NavigationBar` instead of
> `AppBar`. You will be taken to the new screen and action that I
> performed there will be lost or need to handle.

So proper UI guidelines should be met, while we design and develop for the mobile app. Based on guidelines from [material.io](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom#usage)

> **Bottom app bars should be used for:**
>
> - Mobile devices only
> - Access to a bottom navigation drawer
> - Screens with two to five actions
>
> **Bottom app bars shouldn't be used for:**
>
> - Apps with a bottom navigation bar
> - Screens with one or no actions

Refer this link for more useful information about the UI and UX guidelines https://material.io/

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept or upvote so that it will be useful for other users looking solutions for similar kind issue or those who in needy.

Comment: According to material 3 documentation: "Use bottom app bars to draw attention to important actions" https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-app-bar/overview. So the question is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a `scaffold()` with the `bottomNavigationBar()` as you did. Then you could create a list of `Container()` objects each representing a different page. For your `PageView` I'm assuming you have done that, if not then that's the way to do it. Then you could cycle through your pages by setting the `body:` property of the `scaffold` to  `myPages[_currentIndex]` or something like that.

Additionally: Like the comment asks, I am also not sure why you would want both `BottomNavigationBar` and `BottomAppBar` they both do exactly the same thing. In either case the process is the same as what I described above.

Comment: thank you for your response! I have edited my question and added UI image and code snippet to be more clear